# Securely Submitting a Subscription's tax_percent to Stripe API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, stripe-payments

So I have a rails app where I'm selling subscriptions to access content.  For users in NJ, I have to charge them 7% sales tax.  Everywhere else is 0.  So when they register an account with Devise, I record their state.

Then in my SubscriptionsController.rb, I check to see if they live in NJ:

```
 data = if current_user.home_state == "NJ"
    subscription_params.merge(tax_percent: 7)
  else
    subscription_params
  end
  @subscription = ::Subscription.new(data)
```

When the subscription gets created, the subscription table gets updated properly.  I also assumed that when the user makes a purchase this tax_percent would also hit Stripe's API, but it doesn't.

So I tried adding this to the subscription creation form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :tax_percent %>
```

and it does hit Stripe's API, but hits as tax_percent: '', which is null.

So I can always perform a logic check like this:

```
<% if current_user.home_state == "NJ" %>  
   <%= hidden_field :tax_percent, :value => '7' %>
<% end %>
```

But then I'm exposing the value to the client, which can be manipulated.

What's the best 'rails' way to submit this value to Stripe's API?

Comment: Ok, so you still stuck there. Can you show the Stripe API calling code you have? You don't need the filed in form, you just have to pass the value to Stripe API by their corresponding method. Nothing related to the form, I explained it last day. The data you are sending from the form redundant, because u are capturing user choice. The decision you are making based on the value you have in the table. So it is predefined.

Comment: Here's what it shows with the hidden field added: Processing by Koudoku::SubscriptionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token_here", "subscription"=>{"tax_percent"=>"", "plan_id"=>"5", "credit_card_token"=>"cctoken", "last_four"=>"undefined", "card_type"=>"undefined"}, "owner_id"=>"80"}

Comment: No need that. :) Show the Stripe code you have to create the subscription.

Comment: without the field:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token", "subscription"=>{"plan_id"=>"5", "credit_card_token"=>"cctoken", "last_four"=>"undefined", "card_type"=>"undefined"}, "owner_id"=>"79"}

Comment: The controller or the form?

Comment: show your code where  you have `Stripe::Subscription.create(` thing like https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription .

Comment: where is that located?

Comment: Hehe, good question. How are you creating subscription to the Stripe API?

Comment: Yes, but I'm using a plugin called Koudoku.  I didnt write that part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118669/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-johnohfs).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell what's going on based on the code-sample you've provided, but ultimately you want to set the tax-rate on individual users when you Create the Subscription [1].

If you're going to be doing one-off payments, you'll need to also store that information somewhere else on the Customer record.  I might recommend you utilize the `metadata`-parameter [2] of the Customer record.  You can set it by making an Update Customer [3] API Request.  Then, when you're making a charge [4], you'll want to multiply it by whatever tax coefficient you've stored.

Another (probably better) approach, would be to create a pending invoice item [5] for the one-time purchase (without tax being included).  Then create an Invoice [6] with the `tax_percent`-parameter being populated.  And finally, pay the Invoice [7].  This will make a trackable record of purchases made with line-items for their tax percent kept separate.

Hope that helps!

- [1] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription
- [2] https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata
- [3] https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer
- [4] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge
- [5] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem
- [6] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoice
- [7] https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_invoice